# Trouble adding markup in a node with hook_node_view()

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm trying to add a piece of markup with a field in hook_node_view().  It's a little thumb icon for a music site, and I want to overlay this image over another field image (which I'll do with CSS).  However, it's not rendering, and I feel pretty confident that I'm going about it the right way. Here is my addition to the node array:

```
$node->content['like'] = array(
            '#theme' => 'image',
            '#path' => '/sites/default/files/likeimg.png',
            '#alt' => 'like',
            '#prefix' => '<div class="like">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
            '#weight' => -1,
            '#attributes' => array(
                'class' => array('like-img')
            )
        );
```

What am I missing?  I am using Display Suite with fields in blocks, and Omega 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you call the render function of your `like` content inside the `node.tpl.php` ?

```
print render($content['like']);
```

Answer (score 2):

`hook_node_view()` is only called within modules that define node content types (ie. through `hook_node_info()`.

What you want to use is `hook_node_view_alter()`, and render the content in your template file like **Mike Vranckx** suggested.